# android: how to specify multipe listivews

Tags: android, listview

It seems that android has enforced that a listview must have the name android:id="@android:id/list", is there anyway to create multiple listview then? I have two activities which are both listview but have to control different format of Lists, one with image+text the other is just text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend `Activity` (instead of `ListActivity`) and inflate a layout with any number of `ListViews` you like.

Answer (score 1):

The id does not have to be `android:id="@android:id/list"`. You can specify any id by `android:id="@+id/thingsandalsootherthings"`

Comment: Is that true? Check out what synic said in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661073/android-how-to-specify-multipe-listivews

Comment: The link you have there is to this question. You only use `android:id="@android:id/list"` for one `ListView` in a `ListActivity`. If you want your `ListActivity` to have two `ListViews`, then name the second one something else, then use it like a regular widget (e.g., `findViewById()` to get the `ListView`).